# What is causing the horizontal scroll to appear?

Tags: css, debugging, firebug, margin

In the regular version, wide version, and tablet version the scrollbar appears as soon as the window gets to about an inch away from the `site_wrap` container the horizontal scrolling appears.  I can see that if I remove 25px of width from `div#title` that the scroll disappears.

What I can't understand though, is that the container (`site_wrap`) is 1280px, `div.title_wrapper` is auto, and `div#title` is 1234px with a left margin of 46px.

http://brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/expression/blog/

Comment: Your explanation is a little bit confusing. Could you try and be more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of `Blog` menu, it is hidden (opacity is 0) but display is not `none`, which means it still take flow of it's position.

you can check this by set display:none to the `ul` element.

```
<li id="menu-item-813" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page     current-menu-item page_item page-item-178 current_page_item menu-item-813"><a href="http://brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/expression/blog/">Blog</a>
<!-- this--><ul class="sub-menu">
```

you should set its position properly to not over flow the document.

Answer (score 1):

Just define your `#site_wrap`

`margin:0 auto` and `overflow: hidden` **as like this**

```
div#site_wrap {
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Css path is this**

```
http://brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/expression/wp-content/themes/expression/css/bgs/gradient.css
```

Comment: Ahh looks like that did it.  Still not sure why this happened in the first place as nothing was wider than that container but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some miscalculations made in the different `@media` queries which causes this problem. You could easily get rid of the whole horizontal scroll bar (since it isn't needed anyway), by adding this:

```
body { 
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case.  I just removed the responsive.css file that has the media queries in it and it is still showing scrollbars.  I'd like to figure out why this is happening though instead of throwing a bandaid over it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within your `.title_wrapper` or more exactly `.navline`. You should add

```
.navline {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```